# Как получить имя активного окна в VB .net

Tags: visual-basic, vb.net

Пишу на vb.net, интересует получение имени активного окна. В приложении может быть открыто несколько других окон. **Test_name** успешно получается через:

```
    For Each procs In Process.GetProcesses(".")
        Try
            Debug.Print(procs.MainWindowTitle)
        Catch
        End Try
    Next
```

А как получить имена открытых окон в этом же приложении "Информация о магазине" и "Введение события"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В WinApi были ф-ции GetForegroundWindow и GetFocus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @nick_n_a за наводку, нашел [хороший пример](http://pamirych.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-2/), который получает тайтл именно активного окна (в данном случае "Информация о магазине" и "Введение события"):

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)> Public Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowText(ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal text As StringBuilder, ByVal count As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub GetActiveWindow()
    Const nChars As Integer = 256
    Dim handle As Integer = 0
    Dim Buff As New StringBuilder(nChars)

    handle = GetForegroundWindow()

    If GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0 Then
        'Выводит тайтл именно текущего активного окна, т.е. "Введение события"
        Debug.Print(Buff.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```